# How to initialize an ObservedObject from a view created with a NavigationLink?

Tags: swiftui, combine

My apologies if this is not the right question to ask, as I am completely new to SwiftUI and iOS programming in general.  The question indicates what I want to do, and the error I'm getting I believe is a red herring because of the SwiftUI compiler.  It's likely that I am taking the incorrect approach to solving this problem altogether.

I am using XCode Version 11.2.1 (11B500)

View utilizing the ObservedObject:

```swift
struct Results: View {
    var jobId: String
    @ObservedObject var jobDetailService: JobDetailService

    init(jobId: String) {
        self.jobId = jobId
        jobDetailService = JobDetailService(jobId: jobId)
    }

    var body: some View {
        //... view code here
    }

}
```

And it is within this view that I am getting the error (at the ZStack line) "Generic parameter 'C0' could not be inferred".  When I comment out the `NavigationLink` block, the error goes away.  Further, when the `Results` view does not depend on the `jobId` parameter (and we construct `JobDetailService` inline with `@ObservedObject var jobDetailService = JobDetailService()`, this all works.  However, I need to be able to pass the `jobId` parameter to the `JobDetailService` in order to make the network call to fetch and publish the data.

```swift
struct JobList: View {
    @ObservedObject var jobListService = JobListService()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(jobListService.jobs) {job in
                ZStack {
                    JobCard(name: job.fullName, date: job.lastUpdated)
                    NavigationLink(destination: Results(jobId: job.jobId)) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-101-how-not-to-initialize-bindable-objects-6e539d1b5344), and thinking about Asperi's advice on not solely relying on initialization, I opted to do the following:

Remove custom initializer from `JobDetailService` and instead instantiate the service inside my `Results` view.  Then in an `.onAppear` method on the `Results` view, call the `getJobDetail` method from `JobDetailService` which in turn makes the network call that populates the `@ObservedObject`.  This allows me to pass in the parameters I need and control when the network call is made.  Maybe not the right pattern for this problem but it works for my use case for now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following should help you:

Declaration...

```
struct Results: View {
    @ObservedObject var jobDetailService: JobDetailService

    var body: some View {
        //... view code here
    }

}
```

... and usage

```
NavigationLink(destination: Results(jobDetailService: JobDetailService(jobId: jobId))) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

Comment: This compiles, but has the undesired behavior of instantiating `JobDetailService` for every item in the list.  If the service initiates a network call to get details on instantiation, this becomes an unnecessary fetch of data, which is why I'd prefer to defer the fetch to when the detail view is loaded.

Comment: How would I know your internal logic of `JobDetailService` from the topic question? ;) You can make it thing and initiate fetching only by some state variable, which will be toggled, say, in Results .onAppear. You wanted correct initialisation of ObservedObject I shown how to do it. Everything else is yours. :)

Comment: It was not a criticism of your answer, it was additional information to demonstrate why that approach does not work for me.

Comment: Ok, then what stops you in this `@ObservedObject var jobListService = JobListService()` variant from passing `jobId` via property or function? Initialization is not the only way.

Comment: It ends up being a timing issue; because `jobId` isn't initialized yet, I can't pass it on to the other initialization statement for the `jobListService`.  The error I get as a result of doing this is:
Cannot use instance member 'jobId' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available